# Error: No named parameter with the name 'builder' Flutter macOS

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

can someone please explain what to do to fix
"Error: No named parameter with the name 'builder'."?

Code:

```
@override
  final Map<String, _i1.PageFactory> pagesMap = {
    SplashScreenRoute.name: (routeData) => _i1.CupertinoPageX<dynamic>(
        routeData: routeData,
        builder: (_) {
          return const _i4.SplashScreen();
        }),
```

Error:

> Xcode's output: ↳
> leveldb-library-evkvtgfvdszrevdlzrfbvlaovfcr
> lib/routes/router.gr.dart:58:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'builder'.
> builder: (_) {
> ^^^^^^^

[Flutter Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW7G3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your parent class doesn't have a builder method, I also believe you need to use the child method and then builder inside of that.